# VS CODE and python import path confusion

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to understand the appropriate settings for vs code so that I can import local .py files from different sub directories in my vs code project. I ended up solving my problem by adding sub directories I need to import from to `PYTHONPATH` in my `.env` file like so: `PYTHONPATH = "dir_relative_path1;dir_relative_path2..."`. However I also tried fixing my problem by adding directories to `extrapaths` in my `.env` like so: `extrapaths = ["dir_relative_path1", "dir_relative_path2", ...]` but this didn't work.

On top of that I also tried changing `python.analysis.extraPaths` in my `settings.json` file like so `python.analysis.extraPaths= ["dir_relative_path1", "dir_relative_path2", ...]` but this also didn't work.

I was hoping someone could clarify the different usages of `settings.json` vs `.env` and `PYTHONPATH` vs `extrapaths` etc in the context of VS CODE knowing where to look for imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it needs to be clear that vscode uses the opened folder as the workspace. In python, if you want to import modules in different folders, you have to add `pythonpath` to specify the path, otherwise an error will occur.

But in fact, even if you add `pythonpath`, sometimes importing in vscode will still display a yellow warning prompt error. This is because the python extension's intellisense has not detected the imported module, so you need to add `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` to eliminate the warning.

It can be simply understood that the `pythonpath` of `.env` really tells the interpreter that the path of the imported package is that the code can run normally without reporting an error. The `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` in *settings.json* only provides the path for the python extension's intellisense, but it does not work for the code to run. You can see that vscode's interpretation of this setting is `Additional import search resolution paths`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know the purpose of `extrapaths` in .env? I would have thought I should extra directories there but that didn't work.

Comment: extrapaths is not a standard variable of python, it is just a setting in vscode to add additional import resolution paths.